# How to Clear all the list view items of a Static Custom list view in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```js
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;

/**
 * Created by YouCaf Iqbal on 4/6/2016.
 */
public class MainGUI extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<DonorPerson> Donors = new ArrayList<DonorPerson>();
    @InjectView(R.id.findppl) Button _findButton;
    GPSTracker gps;
    String bloodgroup=null;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    DB db; String test="";
    DBCursor cursor;
    DBCollection collection;
    Database dataobj = new Database();
    ArrayList allPPLlat = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLlong = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLNumbers = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLNames = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLImages = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList allPPLEmails = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList SelectedPPLlat = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList SelectedPPLlong = new ArrayList();
    public Spinner mySpinner;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maingui);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Spinner spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.blood_type);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.txt,list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        _findButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getCurrentLatLong();
                dbAsync thrd = new dbAsync();
                thrd.execute();
            }
            //distance=Distance(lablat, lablong, curlat, curlong);
        });
    }
    public void getCurrentLatLong(){
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainGUI.this);
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public class dbAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            getOtherLatLong();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainGUI.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Searching people nearby...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PeopleList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Near by latitudes "+SelectedPPLlat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Near by longitudes "+SelectedPPLlong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void getOtherLatLong() {
        db = dataobj.getconnection();
        collection = db.getCollection("UserDetails");
        //mySpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        //bloodgroup = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
       // BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        //whereQuery.put("employeeId", 5);
        cursor = collection.find();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            DBObject doc = cursor.next();
            // Lats longs used in the next for Loop for calculation distances
            allPPLlat.add(doc.get("lat"));
            allPPLlong.add(doc.get("long"));
            // All these other arraylists are used to store object of a donor person
            allPPLNumbers.add(doc.get("number").toString());
            allPPLNames.add(doc.get("Name").toString());
            allPPLImages.add(doc.get("image").toString());
            allPPLEmails.add(doc.get("email").toString());

        }

        for(int i =0;i<allPPLlat.size();i++){
           double Dist= Distance((double)allPPLlat.get(i),(double)allPPLlong.get(i),latitude,longitude);
            Dist=Dist/1000;
            if(Dist<20){
                Donors.add(new DonorPerson(""+allPPLNames.get(i)+"", ""+allPPLEmails.get(i)+"" ,""+allPPLNumbers.get(i)+"" ,""+allPPLImages.get(i)+""));
            }
        }
    }

    public double Distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double R = 6371.0; // km
        double dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180.0;
        double dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180.0;
        lat1 = lat1 * Math.PI / 180.0;
        lat2 = lat2 * Math.PI / 180.0;

        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2.0) * Math.sin(dLat / 2.0) +
                Math.sin(dLon / 2.0) * Math.sin(dLon / 2.0) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        double d = R * c;
        return d * 1000; // return distance in m
    }
}
```

I have a static custom view called `Donors` declared in one of my classes called `MainGUI`. Whenever the list is displayed and I go back and reopen the list, the same list items appear twice.  I know this happens because the list items are being added to the listview again when I display it without clearing all the data items shown before.  What I want is a way to remove all the existing data items when I reopen the list, so that the items are not duplicated when i access it again.

```
public class PeopleList extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       MainGUI.Donors.clear(); // Clear all the Donors after search
       // this.notifyDatasetChanged();
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.peoplelistview);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        populateListView();

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
         //   MainGUI.Donors.clear(); // Clear all the Donors after search
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<DonorPerson> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.DonorsListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DonorPerson> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(PeopleList.this, R.layout.singlelistitemview,MainGUI.Donors);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Make sure we have a view to work with (may have been given null)
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.singlelistitemview, parent, false);
            }
            // Find the Donor to work with.
            DonorPerson currentPerson = MainGUI.Donors.get(position);
            //Set the Image of the Current Donor
            ImageView DonorImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            //currentPerson.getImage();
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(currentPerson.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
            DonorImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            //imageView.setImageResource(currentPerson.getIconID());
            /* Fill the view
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentCar.getIconID()); */

            return itemView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: MainGUI.Donors.clear();  is not working for me

Comment: clear your adapter item and call notifydatasetchanged

Comment: @SrishtiRoy i will be very thankful if you provide me the code syntax please. I am newbie to android

Comment: Post some code from your `MainGUI`

Comment: @ReazMurshed added

Answer (score 1):

Just use the clear method for your adapter and then call notifydatasetchanged method.

```
_adapter.clear();
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Do this in the class that creates the adapter.

Comment: Tried 
adapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); , but not working

Comment: Have your overrided the onResume method?

Comment: No, i have not overrided onResume

Comment: ok I just read the code better. I think if you clear the donors arraylist in doInBackGround method before populating it the problem will be solved.

    Donors.clear();
    getOtherLatLong();

Answer (score 0):

You can try with overriding the onDestroy() method. Something like this

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    MainGUI.Donors.clear();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Can we rely on onDestroy?